# Timing questions for zip/list comprehension in Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

So I have a dataset that is essential a pair of tuples.

```
D = [(x1,y1), (x2, y2), ... ]
```

I wanted to write some simple python code to convert this where I get a list of only the x elements and another list of the y elements.

```
X, Y = (x1, x2, ...), (y1, y2, ...)
```

Now to my question. I know of various ways to do this in python, but I was curious about which was the most effecient one, so I wrote this script.

```py
import timeit

# Create a dummy dataset
D = [ (i,i) for i in range(int(1e6)) ]

# Decorator for timing the functions
def time_the_func(func):
    def time_func(D):
        avg = []
        for _ in range(32):
            start = timeit.default_timer()
            func(D)
            avg.append(timeit.default_timer() - start)
        return sum(avg) / len(avg)
    return time_func

# Some various approaches

@time_the_func
def test_1(D):
    x, y = [ d[0] for d in D ], [ d[1] for d in D ]

@time_the_func
def test_2(D):
    x, y = list(zip(*D))

@time_the_func
def test_3(D):
    x, y = list(map(lambda x:x[0], D)), list(map(lambda x:x[1], D))

@time_the_func
def test_4(D):
    x, y = map(lambda x:x[0], D), map(lambda x:x[0], D)

# Compare the results
print(test_1(D), test_2(D), test_3(D), test_4(D))
```

Now here are the results

```
0.09848891449998831 0.42325286559375286 0.2815418519375186 1.1091875009583418e-06
```

My questions is simple. Can someone explain these times? I'm curious how zip and map are working under the hood. Why is list comprehension that fastest here? I would have expected that zip would actually be faster.

Comment: Maybe rounding the times can help bettee digest your result? You provide a ton of digits.

Comment: map is the fastest because it delays computation, returns an iterator

Comment: zip just has some overhead

Comment: Ipython %timeit can be helpful in measurement

Comment: I did some quick test and `zip` is actually faster when the array size is small. It only becomes slower when the size is sufficiently large (>1.2e5 in my environment).

Comment: `test_4` doesn't actually make the lists you want. It makes two map objects

Comment: @GZ0 do you know if that it also scales with the size of the objects in the array? In any case, I will do some tests locally.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was just showing that to show that not converting it to lists makes it incredibly fast since it doesn't do any evaluation in reality

Comment: I don't know for sure but my conjecture is that the timings of both approaches grow linearly (with the array size) and `zip` has a larger slope while a smaller bias.

Comment: Note, the bigger your dataset, the more costly `zip(*D)` becomes, because a *giant* tuple `D` must be created to be passed as an argument.